# display spotify tabs after login

Tags: spotify

Before the user has logged in with Facebook the app looks like
[image: pre login]

After the user has authenticated with Facebook it looks like.

[image: post login there are tabs]

I am wondering if they have created their own tabs that just look like the Spotify tabs, as the "songkick conerts" text in the menu and the drop down for "Your locations" doesn't seem to be apart of the Spotify tabs functionality.

In the integration guidelines section on tabs it says [Please be aware that if your application uses the DefaultTabs key (and hence is given a tab bar by Spotify) it will always have a tab selected - there’s no concept of a section within your application that does not belong to a tab in the tab bar](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/01_integration-guidelines.html#tabs).

In the UI guidelines it says ["We want the navigation within the Spotify client to be consistent. Therefore we want you to use our standard tab navigation for your app"](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/03_ui-guidelines.html#topnavigation)

Any ideas on how to replicate this tabs functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're using their own implementation of the navigation tabs menu. We're OK with doing that to extend functionality, as long as the look n feel doesn't break.